# What kind of array is this?

Tags: java

```
public static String[] months = {"January", "February", "March",  
       "April", "May", "June",  
       "July", "August", "September",  
        "October", "November", "December"};
```

Is it called a one dimensional array?

Comment: Usually I would call it a minor vulnerability. `YourClass.months[4] = "December";`

Comment: StackOverflow, the Java Documentation edition.

Comment: Just curious why this question got down voted?

Comment: I think 5 downvotes is rather harsh but the faq states that questions with little effort may deserve a downvote. However it also says that downvoters should consider commenting so take that with a pinch of salt.

Comment: I agree down-voting this is a little too harsh.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  It's a one-dimensional string array.

You only get multi-dimensional arrays by having arrays within arrays, and this array contains only strings and not other arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Would normally be referred to as simply a string array.